# Using existing microservices

Tags: microservices

In the microservice architecture, the main idea is that, every service is a small program, that does one thing and does it well (like unix philosophy)

Some things are common to a variety of projects, eg. user management, contacts, companies, clients, products, payments, etc.

I want to know if there is some kind of repository for microservices that solve there common tasks, so that I don't must reinvent the wheel again.

On [github](http://github.com) it is hard to find something like this and on [docker hub](http://hub.docker.com) are most repos not documented.

So you use some 3th party microservices? Or you create everything yourself?

Answer (score 2):

We use some of the stuff [StdLib](https://stdlib.com) provides and they also have a [registry](https://stdlib.com/search) for others to submit their own stuff. You should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I create all but the concept of micro is opinionated, there are a lot of authentication framework ready in different languages for example this is in PHP

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server

but there is also something in golang, you can use this libraries to make your work simple.

I tried to search something ready to help you but I have the same feeling there aren't around.